# Stop Activity from starting through ADB Shell

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to disable activity from starting through adb shell.

I have followed the suggestion mentioned at following [link](https://www.vantagepoint.sg/hacking-android-activity-intents/#comment-526)

I have added **android:exported = false** on each Activity declared in the AndroidManifest.xml file. But still I am able to start activity using adb shell.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that You cannot do that. using android:exported = false will prevent your activity from getting used by other processes but the activity manager can still access your activity as it is a system process. When we launch an activity from adb shell, we use activity manager (am) to launch it, so it is not possible to prevent that.

But, for launching the activity, the package name is also required. So, You may try a way that your package name and launcher activity is not see by others. And if they don't know those details, they cannot anyway launch it from the shell.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please explain how can I obfuscate package name and launcher activity? I am already using progurad. What else?

Comment: Well again I am not sure to what extent that is possible, still you may google for some recommendations.